# paypal IPN - 'Pending' status when buyer is "USD" and seller is "Euro" account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am working on PaypalIPN, i have seen that if my buyer and seller both have same currency account,It is verify automatically.

if any one of them having different currency account, it is not verify and i have to do from user business account manually?

why it is so?

can some one explain me the real time case?

Comment: It's a PayPal Profile setting. Set 'Website Preferences' to accept and convert all currencies automatically, or open a USD balance.

Comment: Thanks robert,your comment guide me about the setting. Please check the answer, so you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Thanks to ROBERT's comment. It guide me about the settings to do.

The answer is Go to Business acount profile -> More Options  -> Payment Receiving Option.

Make the "Block payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold:"  --  set this to NO.